# Image is being passed in second attempt not in the first attempt in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I need some help regarding the image picker plugin in Flutter. When I press image or gallery in the alert dialog and selecting my image, then background image is being displayed but not passed/saved but when I again press image or gallery in the alert dialog and selecting my image, then background image is being both displayed and passed/saved. what should I do?

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class UserImagePicker extends StatefulWidget {
  UserImagePicker(this.imagePickfn);

  final void Function(File pickedImage) imagePickfn;

  @override
  _UserImagePickerState createState() => _UserImagePickerState();
}

class _UserImagePickerState extends State<UserImagePicker> {
  File _pickedImage;

  void _pickImage() {
    showDialog<ImageSource>(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) =>
          AlertDialog(title: Text("Choose image source"), actions: [
        FlatButton(
          child: Text("Camera"),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, ImageSource.camera),
        ),
        FlatButton(
          child: Text("Gallery"),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, ImageSource.gallery),
        ),
      ]),
    ).then((ImageSource source) async {
      if (source != null) {
        final pickedFile = await ImagePicker().getImage(
          source: source,
          imageQuality: 50,
          maxWidth: 150,
        );
        setState(() => _pickedImage = File(pickedFile.path));
      }
    });
    widget.imagePickfn(_pickedImage);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        CircleAvatar(
          radius: 40,
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          backgroundImage:
              _pickedImage != null ? FileImage(_pickedImage) : null,
        ),
        FlatButton.icon(
          textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          onPressed: _pickImage,
          icon: Icon(Icons.image),
          label: Text('Add an Image'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `_pickImage()` method. You need to move `widget.imagePickfn(_pickedImage);` inside `then` section. Like this.

```
void _pickImage() {
    showDialog<ImageSource>(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) =>
          AlertDialog(title: Text("Choose image source"), actions: [
        FlatButton(
          child: Text("Camera"),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, ImageSource.camera),
        ),
        FlatButton(
          child: Text("Gallery"),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, ImageSource.gallery),
        ),
      ]),
    ).then((ImageSource source) async {
      if (source != null) {
        final pickedFile = await ImagePicker().getImage(
          source: source,
          imageQuality: 50,
          maxWidth: 150,
        );
        setState(() => _pickedImage = File(pickedFile.path));
        widget.imagePickfn(_pickedImage);
      }
    });
  }
```

This is happening because you called the `widget.imagePickfn(_pickedImage);` method outside the then method. The picked image result is returned in the `then` section after closing dialog. That is why, in first attempt your image is not returning, and in second attempt it is returning the previous selected image.

Hope this will solve your problem.

If the above one doesn't solve your problem, you can try this one

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class UserImagePicker extends StatefulWidget {
  UserImagePicker(this.imagePickfn);

  final void Function(File pickedImage) imagePickfn;

  @override
  _UserImagePickerState createState() => _UserImagePickerState();
}

class _UserImagePickerState extends State<UserImagePicker> {
  File _pickedImage;

  void _pickImage() async {
    ImageSource source = await showDialog<ImageSource>(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) =>
          AlertDialog(title: Text("Choose image source"), actions: [
        FlatButton(
          child: Text("Camera"),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, ImageSource.camera),
        ),
        FlatButton(
          child: Text("Gallery"),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, ImageSource.gallery),
        ),
      ]),
    );
    
    if (source != null) {
      final pickedFile = await ImagePicker().getImage(
        source: source,
        imageQuality: 50,
        maxWidth: 150,
      );
      setState(() => _pickedImage = File(pickedFile.path));
      widget.imagePickfn(_pickedImage);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        CircleAvatar(
          radius: 40,
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          backgroundImage:
              _pickedImage != null ? FileImage(_pickedImage) : null,
        ),
        FlatButton.icon(
          textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          onPressed: () => _pickImage(),
          icon: Icon(Icons.image),
          label: Text('Add an Image'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It is not working, again it is accepting input in second attempt.

Comment: Added another solution, Hope the second one will solve your problem.

Comment: it's not working, again the same thing. picking up image in the second attempt. thank you for your reply though.